# destroying PHP $_SESSION array elements

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the problem:
I'm having stored elements is $_SESSION array like this:

```
  $_SESSION['left_side'] = array(); 
  $_SESSION['right_ride'] = array();
```

individual elements being added to arrays are taken from database which i would describe as a tree, for example:

```
30 -- main element
  3030 -- child element
      303010 -- grandchild and so on...
      303011 -- .....
  3031 -- .....
      303110 -- .....
      303111 -- .....
  3032 -- .....
```

i'm using jquery for adding elements to arrays, so the final array is for example like this:

```
$_SESSION['left_side'] = array(30, 3030, 303010, ....);
```

each element has it's own unique name, that i display on site, all elements from those arrays are grouped in divs, added dynamically with jquery. Also each element views sub elements as it is shown on a chart above. I only need to display the sub elements form last element so i use sth like that:

```
$list = array(end($_SESSION['left_side'])
```

And finally, the problem: I want to click for example on 2nd element and in result cut the array only to this element, and display last sub elements.

I've tried sth like this, but it couldn't do the thing:

```
function CutTab($group, &$tab)
{
  $key = array_search($group, $tab);
  $tab = array_slice($tab, 0, $key + 1);
}
```

I would appreciate for any help!
Greetings!!

Comment: The PHP function looks fine to me. Have you validated that the arrays are being set properly? Try `var_dump($_SESSION['left_side']);` or whichever array you are throwing at the function.

Comment: this sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to _"cut the array only to this element"_ to show that one item? You could display the desired item _without_ removing the rest.

Comment: also please clarify _"it couldn't do the thing"_ - what was wrong with the result?